# Repaint QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreewidget

I have a simple class based on QTreeWidget. In some cases (when value one of columns updated), I need to repaint it. I have a function which invokes when I need to update my widget:

```
void TreeWidget::updated()
{
    /* some actions with cells */

    /* here need to repaint widget */
    this->update();
    /* also I'm tried this->repaint(); */
}
```

But line `this->update();` (or `this->repaint();`) gave no results. Widget repaint only when I click on it.

So how can I repaint my widget?

Comment: try with `viewport()->update();`

Comment: @eyllanesc that's work! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classes that inherit from [`QAbstractScrollArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html) as [`QTreeWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html) have [`viewport()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport) which is the widget that must be updated, so in your case the solution is:

```
viewport()->update();
```

If you want to call update from another thread you can use [QMetaObject::invokeMethod()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod):

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(viewport(), "update", Qt::QueuedConnection)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
viewport()->update();
```

Comment: I have a curiosity: how different is your solution with mine? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I learned one interesting thing. As it turned out, you can update widgets in Qt only from the main thread. My function `updated()` was called by another thread, so `this->update()` did not work. However, all slots in Qt are executed just in the main thread, wherever they are called from. In this case, the correct solution would be to wrap `this->update()` inside the slot. Like this:

```
TreeWidget::TreeWidget() 
{
   /* ... */
   connect(this, SIGNAL(signal_update()), this, SLOT(slot_update()));
   /* ... */
}

void TreeWidget::updated()
{
    /* some actions with cells */

    emit signal_update();
}

void TreeWidget::slot_update()
{
    this->update();
}
```

Yeah, it's a less beautiful solution than `this->viewport()->update()` but more correct.

Comment: If you want to execute it from another thread it is not necessary to create a signal, you just need to use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` as I mention in my updated solution :-)